# Overheating laptop Packardbell LS44HR on Linux

Tags: ati, lubuntu, overheating

I have tried Ubuntu 12.10-13.04, Xubuntu and now installed Lubuntu on my Packardbell LS44-HR laptop. On every Linux system my laptop is overheating too fast. I tried to install AMD ATI HD Radeon 66xxM graphics by myself but it gives me this error on fglrx-install.log file.

```
   Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system has make tool. make cannot be found on this system.
fglrx installation requires that the system has gcc tool. gcc cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
```

I really want to use Linux, i hate windows. Please help me :(

And **here is my System Profiler and  Benchmark results**. It's even overheating when i am doing nothing on desktop.

http://needhelp.zohosites.com/

(this one is the best way for showing results because the results is in html file so i uploaded it in a free domain)

Comment: check my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html check the settings for Graphics Cards Radeon

Comment: Add a new answer, do not edit an answer into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo IdeaPad Y560p, also with AMD graphic card.

I solved this by using GNOME2. But now that GNOME2 is gone, I'm using a fork of it called MATE. I've been using Linux Mint with MATE for the last 3 weeks, and I'm VERY happy. Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, that is why I choose it. I bad experiences with Unity and GNOME3.

You can try installing MATE in the operating system you have. No need no install Linux Mint. [More Info of MATE and how to install.](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/download)

Comment: i have the same problem on linux mint 14 MATE too. I think my computer has 2 graphic cards. One of them is ATI HD Radeon 6650M and the other one is the Intel Graphics. I installed psensor program and i think only my graphic card on around 80C but i don't know how to uninstall my drivers now and install intel one.

Comment: Uh! Well, if you have two graphic cards, what you can (maybe) do is switch between them. I haven't been able to try it because my laptop can't do it (Lenovo lied, it's not possible to do it with my model). By doing this you avoid using the ATI card. But you need to be sure you can switch graphic cards. Take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI